# <xsl:sort> not working with <xsl:apply-templates> to display data in table form

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use  `<xsl:sort>` to sort the animals by the atrribute ***@animalName*** in the XML file bellow, while using `<xsl:apply-templates>` to display the animals in a table but it does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

The XML file

```
   <animal animalName="Giraffe" animalId="No. 9">
       <animalNamesInfo scientificName="Giraffa camelopardalis"> </animalNamesInfo>
   </animal>
   <animal animalName="Chimopanzee" animalId="No. 7" >
       <animalNamesInfo scientificName="Pan troglodytes"> </animalNamesInfo>
   </animal>
    <animal animalName="Zebra" animalId="No. 6" >
       <animalNamesInfo scientificName="Equus quagga bοehmi"> </animalNamesInfo>
   </animal>
```

And the xsl code

```
  

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
     <HTML>
      <BODY>
       <table border="5">
        <th>animal_name</th>
        <th>scientific_name</th>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//animal"/>
         <xsl:sort select = "@animalName" />
       </table>
      </BODY>
     </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="animal">
     <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@animalName"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="animalNamesInfo/@scientificName"/></td>
     </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a minor grammar error: `xsl:sort` has to be a child of `xsl:apply-templates`. So change this part to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <HTML>
  <BODY>
   <table border="5">
    <th>animal_name</th>
    <th>scientific_name</th>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//animal">
     <xsl:sort select = "@animalName" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
   </table>
  </BODY>
 </HTML>
</xsl:template>
```

and then, everything should work fine.

Comment: hey @zx485 thanks for the quick reply. I tried performing your change but unfortunately it still does not work. Did you attempt to run the code? Does it execute for you?

Comment: Yes. It did work as desired. And I updated my code part to include the whole template.

Comment: Thank you so much @zx485 I made it work now. I could not for the life of me figure out what was wrong myself. Cheers!